# Hazelcast IMap.tryLock with tryTimeout 100 mills get stuck for more than 1 minute

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are using Hazelcast 3.9.2

2 nodes cluster runs on:
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
with Oracle JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_144"

from 2 up to 20 clients runs on separate VMs:
3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 12 13:21:05 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
with IBM JAVA_VERSION="1.7.1_64"

hazelcast.xml snippet:

```
<map name="lock*">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
</map>
```

That's our hazelcast-client.xml

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config file:///C:/caching/hazelcast-client-config-3.9.xsd">
<group>
    <name>OUR_GROUP_NAME</name>
</group>
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.shuffle.member.list">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">60000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval">5000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.event.thread.count">10</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.event.queue.capacity">1000000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds">35</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled">true</property>
</properties>
<network>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>tvlcacheqa1.blqa.qa:5709</address>
        <address>tvlcacheqa2.blqa.qa:5709</address>
    </cluster-members>
    <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
    <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
    <connection-attempt-period>15000</connection-attempt-period>
    <connection-attempt-limit>1048576</connection-attempt-limit>
<socket-options>
        <tcp-no-delay>false</tcp-no-delay>
        <keep-alive>true</keep-alive>
        <reuse-address>true</reuse-address>
        <linger-seconds>5</linger-seconds>
        <timeout>-1</timeout>
        <buffer-size>64</buffer-size>
    </socket-options>
</network>

<near-cache name="cache*">
    <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
    <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
    <time-to-live-seconds>1800</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>1800</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction eviction-policy="LRU" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" size="10000"/>
</near-cache>
```

> Every preference that not mentioned above are DEFAULT and we do not make preference changes in code.

In batch processing we run this code on every client concurrently:

```
synchronizer.startSyncSection(key, 100);
try {
     doSomeCriticalStuff();
} finally {
     synchronizer.endSyncSection(key);
}
```

This is our `Synchronizer` implementation based on Hazelcast `IMap` features:

```
@Override
public void startSynchedSection(MultiKey<?> key, long tryLockTimeoutInMs, long releaseLockTimeoutInMs) {
    keyNullCheck(key);
    tryLockTimeoutInMs = Math.max(tryLockTimeoutInMs, minimumObtainLockTimeoutInMs);
    if (isClusterReady()) {
        boolean locked = false;
        try {
            locked = this.locks.tryLock(key, tryLockTimeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, releaseLockTimeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        }
        if (!locked) {
            throw new SyncTimeoutException(FAILED_TO_OBTAIN_EXCEPTION + key);
        }
        int lockCounter = incrementLockCounter(key);
    } else {
        throw new SyncTimeoutException(CLUSTER_NOT_READY_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
/** Note This should be called in a FINALLY section!!! */
@Override
public void endSynchedSection(MultiKey<?> key) {
    keyNullCheck(key);
    int lockCounterBefore = getThreadLocalCounter(key.toString()).get();
    if (lockCounterBefore == 0) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        int lockCounterAfter = decrementLockCounter(key);
        if (this.locks.isLocked(key)) {
            this.locks.unlock(key);
        }
    } catch (OperationTimeoutException e) {
        this.logger.warn("endSynchedSection - Lock-> {} was not released properly in Hazelcast because of exception:\n{}\n in Thread={}", key, e
            .getMessage(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Sometimes (very often when we run our batches) thread get stuck on this IMap call:

```
locked = this.locks.tryLock(key, tryLockTimeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, releaseLockTimeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where `this.locks` is `private IMap<String, String> locks;`

## Although we set `tryLockTimeoutInMs = 100ms` thread may be hung for 2 minutes!

Unfortunately, we can't reproduce this situation in a test environment, but we use Dynatrace tool where we see such report in production:
 https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12655866/39863775-74a3da5a-53fc-11e8-96b4-d55bea1f5e06.PNG

I looked through every cluster members & clients logs and did not found something special. Any warnings or connection losses at this times.

## There are some of my assumptions:

1. I call to `IMap.tryLock(key, tryTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, leaseTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` with leaseTime = 30 minutes according to my business requirements, i.e. I make unlock myself like this:`if (this.locks.isLocked(key)) this.locks.unlock(key);` So maybe very frequent calls to `IMap.isLocked(key)` and/or `IMap.unlock(key)` at the same time as `IMap.tryLock` that's a reason?
2. Different JRE's on my member and client-side. And especially Websphere 8.5.5.12 app server and Java 1.7.1_64 from IBM on a **client** side. Maybe because of the method `Unsafe.park(boolean, long)` is using architecture specific code (thus the reason it's 'unsafe') and we see the hangs during this method.
3. It could be some mistakes in my hazelcast.xml preferences, cause we are just starting to use Hazelcast in our project.

Any suggestions about?

Comment: I see the same issue is tracked at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/13034

Comment: @sertug thanks for your care. Yeah, that's the same issue that I opened on Hazelcast GitHub. Unfortunately, I still not solved this problem, so I tried to ask about it on StackOverflow. Until now I forced to check `IMap.isLocked(key)` before `IMap.tryLock(key, time, timeunit, leaseTime, leaseTimeunit)`, but I don't like this solution. Maybe you have any other recommendation to try?